# Blackberry App Development OS 4.5 jQuery Mobile

Tags: blackberry, mobile, jquery-mobile, blackberry-jde

Has anyone used [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com) on Blackberry OS 4.5, 4.6 or 4.7? Can you give me any feedback about the functionalities that the native browsers on those versions would or would not support? I don't need any media related functionalities but other than that did you find any situation where a simple functionality wouldn't work?

In [Mobile Graded Browser Support](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/), these browsers are graded C and they have mentioned jQuery Mobile scripting and CSS won't be provided, falling back to plain HTML and simple CSS. Does this mean I can't use jQuery Mobile at all or I can use with limited capabilities? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Devices running BB OS 6 have a modern WebKit-based browser.  However the older OSs have crummy old browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/ should be an answer to that. BOS under 5 is supported... badly.
It will work as long as you create the app with `progressive enhancement` in mind